# MigLayout - selective component fill

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I am trying to add a `JTabbedPane` to a panel, with buttons above it for controls. I am using MigLayout.

But, I cannot get the `JTabbedPane` to fill without the buttons also filling when they don't need to.

Take the following SSCCE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill()));
    panel.add(new JButton("+"));
    panel.add(new JButton("-"), "wrap");
    panel.add(new JTabbedPane(), "span, grow");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

This produces a panel that looks like this:

[image]

But, if I remove `fill()` from the layout constraints (`JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC()));`), it looks like this:

[image]

How do I make the `JTabbedPane` to fill the content area while the `JButton`s do not fill?

Comment: You have deleted your last question. Have you got the solution?

Comment: I have a solution if you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want a constraint be applied to all cells, don't tell the Layout ;-) Instead, use column and row constraints: three columns and let only the last fill and grow and two rows with the last growing

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "[][][fill, grow]", "[][fill, grow]"));
panel.add(new JButton("+"));
panel.add(new JButton("-"), "wrap");
panel.add(new JTabbedPane(), "span, grow");
```

Comment: !! yay @kleopatra I knew you'd come through lol. I haven't figured out the column and row constraints yet. I was fiddling with it but nothing was working. Thanks.

Comment: Question: why do arguments passed as **column** constraints not apply to **all columns** ? The JTP is in its own **row**, but why don't column constraints apply to the components in the same column as the JTP?